# Why aren't clients running against the same publish/subscribe service getting each other's messages?

Tags: c#, wcf, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to implement publish/subscribe through WCF. My problem is that multiple clients originating from 1 computer work as expected, but clients on another box on the same network don't get the messages.

I'm following this blog tutorial: http://chakkaradeep.wordpress.com/2007/07/30/coding-wcf-publishersusbcriber-model/

I'm hosting the WCF service on an IIS box on my network, and running multiple instances of the test client on 2 separate network machines. 1 machine can bounce messages off the server without problem, but the other machine's clients should be receiving these messages and they just aren't.  Is there a specific config flag I need to be setting to allow what it is I want?

Comment: Could you provide a little more information?  Are you getting any errors when calling Subscribe?  What binding are you using on the endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the code for my project [nvents](http://nvents.org), or simply use it as is.